# flutter firebase database transaction crash

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

I'm trying to create child by using `transaction`.
I did like so.

```
 void _runTransaction(DatabaseReference ref, Map<String, dynamic> data) async { 
      await ref.runTransaction((MutableData tx) async {
         tx.value = data;
         return tx;
     });
  }
```

But app will crash and child won't be created.
Am I doing it wrong?
Does anyone have an idea what went wrong?

Comment: Please submit error logs, device logs, flutter version and `flutter doctor` output in your question.

Comment: Thank you for comment I think I figured out why went wrong.

Comment: In that case please accept an answer or write a new answer to this question & accept it so that the rest of the community can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

As document says
`performs an optimistic-concurrency transactional update to the data at this 
 Firebase Database location.`

I think you can't create with transaction. 
After created the child, then update it with transaction worked.